# how to write a nested php loop that draws an image with few lines of code?

Tags: php

How best can i solve this with less code as possible below is the problem

```
*****

****x

***xx

**xxx

*****

**xxx

***xx

****x

*****
```

this is my code that i want to improve:

```
<?php


   for ($i=0; $i < 5 ; $i++) { 
      if($i >= 1 & ($i <= 3))
      {
        for ($t=0; $t < 5-$i ; $t++)  
         echo "*";
        for ($t=0; $t < $i ; $t++) 
          echo "x";
      }

    else
       for ($j=0; $j < 5 ; $j++) 
        echo "*";
    echo "<br/>";
 }

    for ($f=1; $f < 5 ; $f++) { 
      for ($j=0; $j < $f+1; $j++) 
         echo "*";
      for ($v=3; $v>= $f; $v--) 
         echo "x";
             echo "<br/>";

     }
?>
```

Comment: Are you intentionally skipping `*xxxx` and `xxxxx`?

Comment: yes it should be printed like that using nested loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create string with repeated symbols you can use [`str_repeat`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php). Using this function your code can be simplified to:

```
$num = 5;
for ($i = $num; $i > 1; $i--) {
    echo str_repeat('*', $i) . str_repeat('x', $num - $i) . PHP_EOL;
}

echo str_repeat('*', $num) . PHP_EOL;

for ($i = 2; $i <= $num; $i++) {
    echo str_repeat('*', $i) . str_repeat('x', $num - $i) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Even if you cannot use php core functions, you can write you own function to create same results as `str_repeat`:

```
function createLine($starsCount, $XCount) {
    $result = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $starsCount; $i++) {
        $result .= '*';
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < $XCount; $i++) {
        $result .= 'x';
    }

    return $result;
}
```

And rewrite code as:

```
$num = 5;
for ($i = $num; $i > 1; $i--) {
    echo createLine($i, $num - $i) . PHP_EOL;
}

echo createLine($num, 0) . PHP_EOL;

for ($i = 2; $i <= $num; $i++) {
    echo createLine($i, $num - $i) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: thank very much for your response i like the first approach it has less lines